# Kubernetes logging based on file inside pod

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster having some application pods which are generating multiple log files inside each pod. I want to log those files in a centralized logging solution like elasticsearch. The logs are neither part of stdout/stderr of pod, nor they are mounted as host volume. So basically I need some solution which reads a file from my pod and sends it to elasticsearch or some other logging solution.

Also, I need a solution for same use case but in case of standalone Docker containers not running on Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

> nor they are mounted as host volume

There's your problem: you will want to expose a path that *is* a host volume, such that your existing centralized log slurping tool can see them. The only asterisk I know of when doing that is to be mindful of the permissions, which won't be an issue if your process is running as root, but will be if non-root -- you'll need to volume mount a host directory that has the permissions enabling the container process to open files.

But, I've been around long enough to know that there are always "yes, but"s when dealing with containerizing software, so there are two other alternatives you may consider.

If you are using one of the existing log aggregation tools that expects all logging output to appear on stdout and stderr of the container, then you will want to take advantage of the ability of a root process inside the container to write to any file to send the logs to the "pid 1" of the container's stdout and stderr, in one of at least two ways I know of:

#### log directly to stdout

Some logging frameworks will tolerate being given a "file path" and will cheerfully just open it and begin writing to it:

```
<log4j:configuration>
  <appender name="DOCKER_STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="/proc/1/fd/1"/>
```

*BTW: that is only an example, I don't know right now if log4j tolerates such a thing*

#### redirect to stdout

Similar to the previous tactic, with the advantage of not requiring an application configuration change, and working 100% of the time; but with the disadvantage of making the in-cluster deployment a lot more complicated.

I had to do this very trick with the [kong:0.10](https://hub.docker.com/_/kong/) container, because their logging situation wrote only to files, and did not tolerate pointing at the file descriptors like above.

One would need to modify the `command:` block to launch the application, and then spawn a `tail` for the in-container log, or use some kind of post-deployment trick to `exec` in and start a `tail`:

```
tail -f /the/inside/file.log > /proc/1/fd/1
```

choosing to use "tail -F" if the application rotates the file out from underneath `tail`, and using `nohup tail -F ... &` if you need to protect the process from termination when the post-deployment `exec` shell exits

Answer (score 0):

I would consider persistent volume mounting to your pod.
Employing a side car container like fluentd, you can forward these log files to elasticsearch.
In the case of docker engine, the same volume can be shared between 2 docker process.

Comment: To add to this: Use the emptyDir volume type, which is made exactly for these kinds of scenarios (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir). All containers in your pod whill be able to mount the same emptyDir volum, and there's a 1:1 relationship between emptyDir volume and pod (so cleanup etc happens automatically). Then use OPs suggestion (sidecar). There is a potential perf penalty since each of your pods will be run a separate "shipper" but it might still be the way to go.